# unable to assign variables fetched using php

Tags: php, mysql

here is my code, all is fine i am able to print the values fetched from the database using a while block. but i am unable to assign the values to another variable.

```
<?php

     //all the code to connect etc

     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         echo "<tr>";
         echo "<td>" . $id++ . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";
         echo "</tr>";
     }

     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
         $compname=$row['firstname'];
         $contname=$row['lastname'];
         $contmail=$row['email'];
         $cont=$row['domain'];
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  $compname[]=$row['firstname'];
  $contname[]=$row['lastname'];
  $contmail[]=$row['email'];
  $cont[]=$row['domain'];
}
```

all the variable will be arrays (specifically array items) with their respective values.

> [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

**edit #1**

i will suggest this:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$compname[]=$row['firstname'];
$contname[]=$row['lastname'];
$contmail[]=$row['email'];
$cont[]=$row['domain'];

echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $id++ . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['lastname'] . "</td>";

 echo "</tr>";
}
```

**edit #2**

for eching the items,

```
foreach($cont as $i => $v)
{
    echo $v.'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: ok ill use msqli :) n try. now if i want to use this left side var for another query or simply echo how should i? echo $cont; or echo cont[]; ?

Comment: suppose i remove the while as i am sure i only have one row in my db. then what chenges woould be suggested? :)

Comment: i dont want arrray variables in the first place. suppose i dont use while to fetch multiple rows. As i have only one row as output to my query. is Key value pair something possible?

Comment: what if you will have more than one row in future? you will change your code?

Comment: well my application always requires just one row:) i plan to insert these row variable into another table, with a few changes

Comment: i don't see what is the problem with arrays. even if it is one row, it will be in the array you can access it.